# Numbering appears from right to left in mixed language

Tags: overleaf, polyglossia, hebrew, bidi

I'm having trouble with section numbering appearing in a reverse order and reversed parentheses in formulas for a file mainly written in English, with some Hebrew at the first two pages.
I've tried most of the suggested ideas in similar posts and none have worked.
This is the headline of the file:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr, setspace}%, extsizes}
\usepackage{geometry,polyglossia,fontspec,csquotes,wrapfig}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\geometry{
inner=2cm,outer=3cm,
top=\dimexpr 1in+24pt,% standard offset+topmargin+headheight+headsep
headsep=9pt,
textheight=590pt,
}

%polyglossia packages - polyglossia must be first
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{bidi}
\usepackage{enumitem}


\setmainlanguage[variant=british]{english}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}
```

I'm also attaching some examples:
[image]

The numbering here supposed to be 4.2, and the parentheses are reversed.
[image]

The numbering of sections is also reversed.

I'll appreciate any help.

Comment: This used to happen with older versions of `bidi`? Perhaps try setting your Overleaf project's TeX Live version to a newer one e.g. TL2020. https://www.overleaf.com/blog/new-feature-select-your-tex-live-compiler-version/

Comment: it worked! thank you!!!